# Julia: sort two arrays (like lexsort in numpy)

Tags: numpy, julia

**Python example**

---

In Numpy there is [lexsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to sort one array within another:

> Given multiple sorting keys, which can be interpreted as columns in a
> spreadsheet, lexsort returns an array of integer indices that
> describes the sort order by multiple columns.

So taking the following example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])
b = np.array([10,8,11,4,8,0])

sorted_idx = np.lexsort((b,a))
print(b[sorted_idx])
# [ 8 10 11  0  4  8]
```

So this sorts b *within* a as we can see like:

```
1 1  1      2  2  2
8 10 11     0  4  8
```

I can't find anything similar in Julia so I wonder how this can be achieved? In my case two columns is sufficient

---

**Julia**

So lets take the same data to figure that out:

```
a = Vector([1,1,1,2,2,2])
b = Vector([10,8,11,4,8,0])
```

---

**Little benchmark**

```
using StructArrays
using DataFrames
using BenchmarkTools


a = rand(100000)
b = rand(100000)

function f1(a, b)
    return sortperm(StructArray((a, b)))
end

function f2(a, b) 
    return sortperm(DataFrame(a=a,b=b, copycols=false))
end
        
function f3(a, b)
    return sortperm(collect(zip(a, b)))
end



@btime f1(a,b)
@btime f2(a,b)
@btime f3(a,b)
```

Giving:

```
6.075 ms (8 allocations: 781.50 KiB)
13.808 ms (8291 allocations: 5.93 MiB)
15.892 ms (7 allocations: 2.29 MiB)
```

So `StructArray` is almost twice as fast as the other two and uses less memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the DataFrames solution but a bit more lightweight in terms of dependencies, a nice solution is to use the [StructArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StructArrays.jl) package, which lets you treat a pair of arrays as *if* it were an array of tuples, *without* making a copy of the data, which you can then sort (tuples sort lexicographically):

```
using StructArrays
i = sortperm(StructArray((a, b)))
```

Instead of finding the permutation array `i` and doing `b[i]`, you can also do:

```
sort!(StructArray((a, b)))
```

which sorts both `a` and `b` in-place lexicographically by `(a[j], b[j])`.

Comment: Very good solution! I didn't know the StructArrays.jl package, I'll start using it.

Comment: Cool that this also works without copying the data

Comment: This is around twice as fast as the other solution and uses less memory (see edit), thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort` and `sortperm` functions with a vector of tuples:

```
julia> a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2];

julia> b = [10, 8, 11, 4, 8, 0];

julia> x = collect(zip(a, b))
6-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 10)
 (1, 8)
 (1, 11)
 (2, 4)
 (2, 8)
 (2, 0)

julia> sort(x)
6-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 8)
 (1, 10)
 (1, 11)
 (2, 0)
 (2, 4)
 (2, 8)

julia> sortperm(x) #indices
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 1
 3
 6
 4
 5
```

Comment: Aaah interesting! Pretty cool Julia does that automatically already when tuple are given, didn't know that. Won't zip be expensive for big vectors?

Comment: I made a benchmark to test:
```julia
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = rand(10_000);

julia> y = rand(10_000);

julia> @btime collect(zip($x, $y))
  11.500 μs (2 allocations: 156.30 KiB)
```

Answer (score 3):

With DataFrames.jl it can be a bit shorter to write:

```
using DataFrames
sortperm(DataFrame(a=a,b=b, copycols=false))
```

`copycols=false` is to avoid unnecessary copy of vectors when creating a data frame. If you do not care about performance and want a short code then you can even write:

```
sortperm(DataFrame(; a, b))
```